# value not getting binded with this.name under a $scope method in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have created an application in AngularJS with having **[Skinny AngularJS Controllers](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-skinny-angularjs-controllers#disqus_thread)**. The application is working fine but the issue is that I am having a `$scope.submit` method through which I need to set a value to `this.name`, and through `this.getDetails` method I need to get the value, but unfortunately the value is not getting binded with the `this.name` variable.

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9trrf6fu/)**

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ControllerOne', function ($scope) {

    this.getDetails = function () {
        return this.name;
    };

    $scope.submit = function () {
        this.name = "Messi";
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `$scope.submit`, the `this` refers to `$scope`, and not your controller.
This would for instance work:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ControllerOne', function ($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.getDetails = function () {
        return vm.name;
    };

    $scope.submit = function () {
        vm.name = "Messi";
    };
});
```

IMO, you should avoid mixing $scope and this, and just use `this`. Don't forget to use `one.submit()` in your HTML :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ControllerOne', function ($scope) {
    this.getDetails = function () {
        return this.name;
    };

    this.submit = function () {
        this.name = "Messi";
    };
});
```

Edit: Check this guide on the benefits of using a variable to store `this`, and why I named it `vm` https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controllers

Answer (score 1):

Different context for this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ControllerOne', function ($scope) {
    var _this = this;

    this.getDetails = function () {
        return _this.name;
    };

    $scope.submit = function () {
        _this.name = "Messi";
    };
});
```